# Update package.json if local package version different

Tags: node.js, npm, version, package.json

I am relatively new to node js, npm. 
It seems there is a difference between what packages have been installed on my system and what packages are beeing installed by npm install/ package.json.

Question: how can i check version of my local packages against my package.json and update my package.json accordingly.
I have tried npm shrinkwrap but this generates a different file format.

Current situation:

```
Gulp: 

local version 1.1 

global version 1.1

Package.json version 1.0
```

What i would like to achieve is for all versions to be matched to my local version in the package.json like this:

```
Gulp

Local version 1.1

Global version 1.1

P.json 1.1
```

Given there are thousands if not more packages im trying to use automation :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm update --save-dev` for update and save devDependencies and `npm update --save` for dependencies

Comment: Wont that update my package.json to the latest available versions? Im trying to match my installed versions in my package.json not vise versa

Comment: running npm update --save-dev will not check my local packages and update my package.json. It will however update my local packages to the Latest version aswell as update my package.json which is not what i want